# Optimize code that imports few files from same directory

Tags: reactjs

So I've got something like this:

```
import Home from "./pages/home";
import File1 from "./pages/items/File1";
import File2 from "./pages/items/File2";
import File3 from "./pages/items/File3";
import Notes from "./pages/items/Notes";
import File4 from "./pages/items/File4";
```

and

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
// some code
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/> 
              <Route exact path="/file1" component={File1}/>
              <Route exact path="/file2" component={File2}/>
              <Route exact path="/file3" component={File3}/>
              <Route exact path="/notes" component={Notes}/>
              <Route exact path="/file4" component={File4}/>
            </Switch>
// some code
    );
  }
}
```

What's the best way to optimize these imports in case I want to add e.g. 30 randomly named components from 'items' directory?

Ps. Components' names are demonstrative.

Comment: Optimize for what? Is it too slow or consumes too much memory? What concrete problem are you having with it?

Comment: I'd like to short code if these is any possible way instead of having e.g. 50 imports and 50 Routes which is like 100 lines of code.

Comment: This is as short as you can get. In Typescript there is one `import` line per file and then in React there is one line per `Route`, this is normal and expectable. In a system I work on, a similar file on it has over 250 lines, mostly imports and routes. What's the problem of having more lines? This is hardly a problem, and in any sizable website, it will grow.

Answer (score 0):

use lazy import https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <OtherComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: useful link https://web.dev/code-splitting-suspense/

Comment: Got you, but in case if I have e.g. 50 separated components in same directory to import, it's min. 100 lines, no?